# AnythingSlider in a "random access" mode

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I would like to use AnythingSlider to implement a multiple-panel login dialog. One requirement is that I will want to navigate to different panels in a random order, and I want the transitions to only show the source and destination panels, none of the intervening ones.

For example:

- Panel 1 is the primary login step (username / password)
- Panel 2 is a secondary login step (security question)
- Panel 3 is a password recovery panel
- Panel 4 is something else again

Navigation between panels is controlled by buttons and logic outside of the slider element.

If the user starts at Panel 1, and wants to try Password Recovery, I would like to slide in Panel 3 from the right without seeing panel 2 on the way by.

Is there a way to accomplish this with AnythingSlider?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the [`mode` option](https://github.com/CSS-Tricks/AnythingSlider/wiki/Appearance-Options#mode-horizontal) to `fade` would work best for you - it stacks the slides on top of each other and cross-fades between the panels instead of sliding.

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ycUB6/6047/).